# 'PipeTransport' object has no attribute '_output' - error

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, playwright

I keep on getting the error:
'PipeTransport' object has no attribute '_output'
I was following the youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wO7K-SoUHM&list=PLRzwgpycm-Fjvdf7RpmxnPMyJ80RecJjv&index=14&ab_channel=JohnWatsonRooney

And the link I was scraping was:
https://jobs.goodlifefitness.com/listjobs/

the code I used was:

```
import scrapy

class JobsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'jobs'

def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request('https://jobs.goodlifefitness.com/listjobs/',
                         meta={'playwright': True})

def parse(self, response):
    yield{
        'text': response.text
    }
```

Comment: please include the full text from the traceback.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error while executing a similar code. In my case, the log also contained NotImplementedError.
I was running the code on Windows 10. It turns out, that scrapy-playwright does not support Windows. I checked on Linux, it works fine.